# Same color text text looking different color

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why this title and text look different color even though they have both same hex color. I mean "The making of magic" and whatever you see below it, if you look close they sort of do look like different colors. Why?

Live page:
http://goo.gl/o5n99M

Image:

[image]

Comment: It looks the same to me...

Comment: It's because "The making of magic" is inner a H1 and strong tags.

Comment: `font-weight: bold`...Between the font weight and font size being larger, the colors will appear slightly different. http://jsfiddle.net/9hs5dd36/1/

Comment: I really don't get anybody giving negative points. Some people rate questions whether they like the question or not. I have a need of this question being answered and for that I posted a question, why would anyone tag it negative? .. Insane people.

Answer (score 4):

It's an optical illusion caused by larger fonts or bold text. They are exactly the same colour; the difference is in your head.

Answer (score 0):

"The making of magic" is in a `<strong>` tag, so it is bold. The "We curate" is not bold. To fix this you can either taking away the `<strong>` tag from "The making of magic" or your can give the `<strong>` tag to the "We curate"